# Android SQLite update - why whereargs?

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

The Android SDK documentation for SQLite provides an `update` method which takes as its parameters four values - `table, values, whereClause, whereArgs`.  The first three make complete sense.  However, it is not clear to me that using `whereArgs` with a `whereClause` containing `?'s` as opposed to sending out a fully prepared `whereClause` offers any benefits - either in terms of security (there is no suggestion that this somehow helps to sanitize the SQL) or speed.  So what then are the benefifts of going down that route instead of simply passing a full `where` string and a null `whereArgs`?

Comment: In addition to helping a bit with SQL injection attacks (see Danail's answer), using arguments handles escaping of necessary characters (e.g., apostrophes). Use arguments wherever possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security is definitely an issue. If you use string concatenation, you are vulnerable to SQL Injection. Using `?` and `whereArgs` does indeed sanitize the input so you are safe.

There is also the case of prepared statements - you compile them only once and then bind different values for each arguments placeholder. This will give you a benefit in terms of performance. You can't get that with your approach.

Comment: Fair enough. I wonder why the docs do not clarify that `update` is more than just a "convenience" method and its data binding offers more security, handles char escaping...

Answer (score 2):

The docs say:

> String: You may include ?s in the where clause, which will be replaced by the values from whereArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.

This is slightly misleading. No "replacement" takes place actually. Instead the `?`s are variables and the `whereArgs` are values that are bound to those variables, and this binding happens inside the sqlite SQL program.

Using variable binding avoids issues such as SQL injection without the need to sanitize inputs.

Similar mechanism would be beneficial for performance in case you were executing the same SQL program over and over again with different values for variables. You only need to compile the SQL once. Android SQLite mechanism for that is [`SQLiteStatement`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html#executeInsert()) (see the `bind...()` methods in its `SQLiteProgram` superclass).